# Why java process can start even the xms was set to large than the physical memory?

Tags: java, memory

I tried to test the java application can start or create in order to pre-check the xms/xmx configurations.
I just wrote a simple class, do Nothing just print hello world, and running the following commands:

```
javac -Xms3000m A
```

And It succeed, I used 'free -m' to get the free memory.

[root@centosvm64 bin]# ***./java -Xms3590m A***
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000007654a0000, 2509635584, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 2509635584 bytes for committing reserved memory.
 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /root/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/hs_err_pid51400.log
**[root@centosvm64 bin]# free -m

             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:           981        896         84          0         17        432

-/+ buffers/cache:        446        534

Swap:         1983        157       1826**

[root@centosvm64 bin]# ***./java -Xms3000m A***

So my question is :
(1) I just got ~1G physical memory, why -Xms3000m can work and start the process but -Xms3590 not?
(2) Did the -Xms option mean the process will must reserve at least that amount of memory and then start or something else? Obviously, from the previous test, it's not. I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: what do you use for your virtualization? can you check the vm settings? my hypothesis would be that you have dynamic memory allocation option enabled for that vm

Comment: Because of virtual memory.

Comment: @lvan I used vm fusion 8.5.0 on mac OS 10.11.6 with 1024 MB memory and 1 processor core.

Answer (score -1):

Total memory you can using is sum of physical memory and swap memory.

In this case, sum of your physical memory and swap memory (subtract the memory you have used) is larger than 3000M and smaller than 3590M.

Comment: you mean 1826 + 981 = 2807 is less than 3000M ?

Comment: you need add the memory that is cached by your system. 981 + 446 + 1983 = 3410. It's greater than 3000 and less than 3590.

Comment: I just tried your method to calculate the free memory. it showed that the calculation was wrong. Because I tested with a result of 3798m but the process failed to start up by just -Xms3500m